# Dominiated convergence application

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_{n}$, $f$, $g$ measurable functions on $(\Omega,F,\mu)$ and $lim_{n \to \infty}$. 
Let $f_{n}=f$ pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere, $|f_{n}|\leq g$ for all $n$, $\int_{\Omega} |g|^{p}d\mu <\infty$ for some $p \in [1,\infty)$.
I have to show that $lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\Omega}|f_{n}-f|^{p} d\mu=0$ using the dominated convergence theorem

(so: $f_{n}$ meausrable, $f=lim f_{n}$ a.e., there existst a $g \leq 0$ s.t. $|f_{n}|\leq g$ a.e. with $\int g d\mu < \infty$, then $\int f d\mu = lim \int f_{n} d\mu$).

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Can you find a dominating function for $\lvert f_n - f\rvert^p$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see that since $|f_n|\leq |g|$ then $|f|\leq |g|$ as well.

Thus, $|f_n-f|\leq |f|+|f_n|\leq 2|g|$

Thus, $|f_n-f|^p\leq 2^p |g|^p$

Also, we have that $2^p|g|^p$ is integrable (with finite integral).

Thus, using the dominated convergence theorem,

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega} |f_n-f|^p=\int_\Omega\lim_{n\to\infty} |f_n-f|^p=0 $

QED.